# Pytest: How to locate a FutureWarning and fix it?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pytest, future-warning

In my current project when I run my tests (with `pytest`) I get this output (besides others):

```
ml_framework/tests/test_impute.py: 8 warnings
ml_framework/tests/test_transform_pipeline.py: 9 warnings
ml_framework/tests/test_data_transforms.py: 27 warnings
ml_framework/tests/test_jsonizer.py: 4 warnings
  /home/sondracek/anaconda3/envs/p3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:70: FutureWarning: Pass standardize=False as keyword args. From version 1.0 (renaming of 0.25) passing these as positional arguments will result in an error
    warnings.warn(f"Pass {args_msg} as keyword args. From version "
```

This `FutureWarning` is quite clear - from version 1.0 (I'm using `0.24` at the moment) there will be change to some parameters and I will not be able to pass `standardize` as positional arguments.

But the question is - **How can I locate where should I change this positional argument to a keyword one?**

I could go to `validation.py` that is mentioned in the warning output, but there is general `_deprecate_positional_args` function which does not tell me which code call it.

In this particular case I'm guessing this will come from `PowerTransformer` imported from `sklearn.preprocessing` which is used in my code, has `standardize` parameter and is tested in the listed tests. **Is there a general way how to find the cause of that easily for any `FutureWarning`?** Or do I need to check all my codes and try to find it somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pytest let you raise a `FutureWarning` as an error, this way it points to the code location where the warning was raised, the simplest way is through the warning flag

```
pytest -W error::FutureWarning test_script.py
```

or inside `test_script.py` through [pytestmark](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#globalvar-pytestmark)

```
pytestmark = pytest.mark.filterwarnings("error::FutureWarning")
```

you can read more about specifying the action being taken on a Warning [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest-mark-filterwarnings) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warning-filter).

**Example**

Considering the following dummy example `test_transform.py` script

```
# test_transform.py
import pytest


pytestmark = pytest.mark.filterwarnings("error::FutureWarning")


def test_transformer_boxcox():

    from sklearn.preprocessing import PowerTransformer
    
    pt = PowerTransformer('box-cox', False)
    
    assert True
    

def test_transformer_yeo_johnson():

    from sklearn.preprocessing import PowerTransformer
    
    pt = PowerTransformer('yeo-johnson', False)
    
    assert True
```

and running on terminal

```
pytest test_transform.py > logs.log
```

the logs show me exactly that `PowerTransformer` raised the `FutureWarning`.

```
===================================================== test session starts =====================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.6, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/jovyan/work
collected 2 items

test_transform.py FF                                                                                                    [100%]

========================================================== FAILURES ===========================================================
___________________________________________________ test_transformer_boxcox ___________________________________________________

    def test_transformer_boxcox():
    
        from sklearn.preprocessing import PowerTransformer
    
>       pt = PowerTransformer('box-cox', False)

test_transform.py:11: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

args = (<[AttributeError("'PowerTransformer' object has no attribute 'copy'") raised in repr()] PowerTransformer object at 0x7fa0bda14d50>, 'box-cox', False)
kwargs = {}, extra_args = 1, args_msg = 'standardize=False'

    @wraps(f)
    def inner_f(*args, **kwargs):
        extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
        if extra_args <= 0:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
    
        # extra_args > 0
        args_msg = ['{}={}'.format(name, arg)
                    for name, arg in zip(kwonly_args[:extra_args],
                                         args[-extra_args:])]
        args_msg = ", ".join(args_msg)
        warnings.warn(f"Pass {args_msg} as keyword args. From version "
                      f"{version} passing these as positional arguments "
>                     "will result in an error", FutureWarning)
E       FutureWarning: Pass standardize=False as keyword args. From version 1.0 (renaming of 0.25) passing these as positional arguments will result in an error

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:72: FutureWarning
________________________________________________ test_transformer_yeo_johnson _________________________________________________

    def test_transformer_yeo_johnson():
    
        from sklearn.preprocessing import PowerTransformer
    
>       pt = PowerTransformer('yeo-johnson', False)

test_transform.py:20: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

args = (<[AttributeError("'PowerTransformer' object has no attribute 'copy'") raised in repr()] PowerTransformer object at 0x7fa0bd02f750>, 'yeo-johnson', False)
kwargs = {}, extra_args = 1, args_msg = 'standardize=False'

    @wraps(f)
    def inner_f(*args, **kwargs):
        extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
        if extra_args <= 0:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
    
        # extra_args > 0
        args_msg = ['{}={}'.format(name, arg)
                    for name, arg in zip(kwonly_args[:extra_args],
                                         args[-extra_args:])]
        args_msg = ", ".join(args_msg)
        warnings.warn(f"Pass {args_msg} as keyword args. From version "
                      f"{version} passing these as positional arguments "
>                     "will result in an error", FutureWarning)
E       FutureWarning: Pass standardize=False as keyword args. From version 1.0 (renaming of 0.25) passing these as positional arguments will result in an error

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:72: FutureWarning
=================================================== short test summary info ===================================================
FAILED test_transform.py::test_transformer_boxcox - FutureWarning: Pass standardize=False as keyword args. From version 1.0 ...
FAILED test_transform.py::test_transformer_yeo_johnson - FutureWarning: Pass standardize=False as keyword args. From version...
====================================================== 2 failed in 0.71s ======================================================
```

Comment: Thanks, that's good solution! I know about `-W` flag but didn't realize it's possible to use it in such way. Do you know whether something similar is possible to use for finding other warnings that happens during import in `test_something.py`?

Comment: @Nerxis like a DeprecationWarning ?

Comment: Yes, exactly this one.

Comment: @Nerxis I think that if you're importing the function `from module import function` inside the test function you should be able to catch Deprecation Warnings applying the same logic.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it just seems it does not work when you import something outside test function. But it's a bit different issue, so I will try to find out.